# Arch Linux display freezes after closing any games that use LWJGL

Tags: xorg

On both of my Arch Linux boxes if I run any game written in java that uses LWJGL the display freezes and the only way to fix it is to kill Xorg, but everything else on the laptop runs like normal, when i use CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE it kills Xorg and the display unfreezes for like a second before Xorg dies. Does anyone know a way to fix this? Also I'm using i3 with amd graphics.

Comment: You mention you're using `i3`.  Does the same problem happen with other window managers/desktop environments?  There are numerous problems running games in tiling WMs, including some java-specific ones.